# Downgrade homestead(vagrant) with php7.1 to php7.0 -mycrypt not supported

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

Am using both laravel 4.2 and 5.4 projects with homestead in vagrant.
mcrypt is not supported in php7.1 so it throws error for larvel 4.2 project.
Is there a way to install homestead with specific php version?
or else can anybody suggest a workaround for the mcrypt problem.

Comment: The problem is that [the mcrypt project is dead](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt). Here's [the official page on it](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php). You need to consider upgrading.

Comment: ya i saw that ,openssl is suprtd in laravel 5.but am using 4.2.is there a way to instal homstead with php7.0.that will solve my problm.